# Remove leap day from date sequence

Tags: r, date

I am trying to remove leap day from my date sequence, however, I am getting error. Please help.

```
Dates=as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("1979-01-01"), to=as.Date("2016-12-31"),by="days"))
names(Dates)= "Dates"
Dates$year=as.numeric(format(Dates$Dates, "%Y"))
Dates$month=as.numeric(format(Dates$Dates, "%m"))
Dates$day=as.numeric(format(Dates$Dates, "%d"))

if [(Dates$month == 2 & Dates$day == 29)]
    Dates=Dates[]
```

Date sequence with no leap day

Comment: `library(lubridate); Dates[!(month(Dates$Dates)==2 & day(Dates$Dates)==29),]`

Comment: The PCICt package has a POSIXct-like class for 365 day years.

Comment: Thank you all for helping this sort out. Got some good suggestions to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get plenty of answers here with a variety of packages, but you can do this with base R and the `format()` function. You extract the month and day and then use negation to exclude the leap dates:

```
myDates <- myDates[!(format(myDates$Dates,"%m") == "02" & format(myDates$Dates, "%d") == "29"), , drop = FALSE]
```

`format()` returns characters, so thus we need to put `"02"` and `"29"` in quotes.

*Addressing question in comments*

The code above does precisely what you are asking:

```r
myDates=data.frame(seq(as.Date("1979-01-01"), to=as.Date("2016-12-31"),by="days"))
names(myDates)= "Dates"
nrow(myDates)
#> [1] 13880
myDates <- myDates[!(format(myDates$Dates,"%m") == "02" & format(myDates$Dates, "%d") == "29"), ,drop = FALSE]
nrow(myDates)
#> [1] 13870
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your looking into this. All I want is date sequence with no leap day i.e  After running the code, I should get 13870 observations instead 13880 as there are 10 leaps years from 1979-2016.

Comment: @Hydrologist - the code above does what you're asking; see above.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you messed up with dataframe and vectors? May consider below code and library`tidyverse` and `library(lubridate)`:

```
> Dates=seq(as.Date("1979-01-01"), to=as.Date("2016-12-31"),by="days")
> find_leap = function(x){
+   day(x) == 29 & month(x) == 2 
+ }
> 
> Dates[find_leap(Dates)]
 [1] "1980-02-29" "1984-02-29" "1988-02-29" "1992-02-29" "1996-02-29"
 [6] "2000-02-29" "2004-02-29" "2008-02-29" "2012-02-29" "2016-02-29"
```

Comment: Thank you. This will give me leap year in my date sequence. I want to remove leap day.

Comment: @Hydrologist, just add `!` to reverse the selection: `Dates[!find_leap(Dates)]`. Hope that helps.